# i create a new laravel 5.6 website and the server.php file deletes itself

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

When I create a new Laravel 5.6 website and use `php artisan serve` in the console the website loads in the browser, but when I refresh the page the **server.php** file deletes itself and I get a page error.

Below is an image of the error message:

[image: showing the error message]

This is the text of the error:

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\test3\server.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')
>   in Unknown on line 0

Comment: plz provide the error code if you can, some users in some countries can not open images

Comment: have you checked if this file is __really__ being removed? check if it exists in directory given in error message

Answer (score 3):

`server.php` file is missing so you got this error, Some antivirus considers that the **server.php** file is a virus, So he simply removes it.

You can also manually create **server.php** file

1. Open the link and copy all the code: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/server.php
2. save in Notepad file and set name **server.php**
3. Copy the **server.php** file and paste it *inside your Laravel project*

Run your project again in browser Now you will not get an error and your Laravel project will work properly.

Comment: yup avast was the culprit !

Answer (score 0):

You need to update both composer and laravel installer. This happens maybe you have latest composer version but outdated laravel installer. To do this, run **composer update** then **composer global require "laravel/installer"** to update laravel installer as well.

Lastly check the server requirement for your laravel version. Laravel 5.6 requires at least PHP >= 7.1.3. So make sure you have that in your serve. If not then you probably need to update it.

After the updates, try to install laravel again.

EDIT: I confirmed the issue, it seems a bug in laravel installer

The solution will to create another project then copy the newly created server.php this will solve it.

Also if your anti-virus is avast, you need to add exception there, I have a response in GitHub that avast considers it as a threat.